# PHP POST request to Android Volley POST request

Tags: php, android, post, request, android-volley

I have code in PHP that handled API requests for me. Now I need to convert this code into an Android application so that the API can be called directly from Android.

Therefore, I found a Volley implementation, but the API still returns "Invalid request - request is empty".

I am attaching PHP code. Thank you in advance

PHP:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Prague');
$login = "email";
$wpass = "password";

$auth = sha1($login.sha1($wpass).date('H', time()));
$command = 'ping';


$request = '{
  "request":
  {
    "user":     "'.$login.'",
    "auth":     "'.$auth.'",
    "command":  "'.$command.'"
  }
}';

$url = 'https://myapi.com/json';

// POST data
$post = 'request='.urlencode($request);

// inicializace cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// nastavení URL a POST dat
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);

// odpověď chceme jako návratovou hodnotu curl_exec()
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

// doba, po kterou skript čeká na odpověď
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);

// vypnutí kontrol SSL certifikátů
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

// provedení volání
$res = curl_exec($ch);

$json = json_decode($res);

...
?>
```

Android:

```
JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            String email = "email";
            String pass = "password";
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Prague"));
            String time = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            String auth = "encrypted ...";

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("user", email);
            jsonObject.put("auth", auth);
            jsonObject.put("command", "ping");
            String payload = jsonObject.toString();
            String query = URLEncoder.encode(payload);

            postData.put("request=", query);

        } catch (JSONException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(root.getContext());
        String url ="https://myapi.com/json";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, postData,
                response -> {
                    System.out.println(response);
                }, error -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

EDIT: I need to convert this PHP request code to Android Volley request code. PHP file will not be used! It serves only as an example of a functional solution in PHP, which I want to use instead in Android Volley

EDIT #2: The API call from Android Volley works, but sending JSON POST data ("request") is probably poorly implemented by me.

Comment: I do not know what the data will be returned by your curl, but will it be possible that you should use $json = json_encode($res) instead of $json = json_decode($res) ?

Comment: @KenLee The PHP code is fine, but I want to use the Android Volley request instead of the PHP request ... The PHP code will not be used

Comment: If  API still returns "Invalid request - request is empty", it is highly likely that your Android Volley request is having problem so that request is empty. Please double check the API username / auth / querystring

Comment: @KenLee I think I solve it...btw I have another problem...wait a minute, I will create comment

Comment: @KenLee I solved it :)

Comment: Great to note that you have solved it. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `getBody()` method.